# Including first and last elements in list comprehension

Tags: python

I would like to keep the first and last elements of a list, and exclude others that meet defined criteria without using a loop. The first and last elements may or may not have the criteria of elements being removed.

As a very basic example,

```
aList = ['a','b','a','b','a']

[x for x in aList if x !='a']
```

returns `['b', 'b']`

I need `['a','b','b','a']`

I can split off the first and last values and then re-concatenate them together, but this doesn't seem very Pythonic.

Comment: Read about list slicing. It is _very_ Pythonic.

Comment: Could you please offer more clarity about what you want?  It is not clear if you want the first few elements off the front and the back of the list and not the rest in the middle, or if you want to exclude certain values from the middle of the list and also keep the very first and very last elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use slice assignment:

```
>>> aList = ['a','b','a','b','a']
>>> aList[1:-1]=[x for x in aList[1:-1] if x !='a'] 
>>> aList
['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: Works if and only if the first and last characters are `'a'`. If they're not, they will be included twice.  I *think* the OP probably wants simply to make the first and last elements immune from de-selection whatever they are.

Comment: @jez: Thanks -- changed.

Answer (score 5):

Yup, it looks like dawg’s and jez’s suggested answers are the right ones, here.  Leaving the below for posterity.

---

Hmmm, your sample input and output don’t match what I think your question is, and it is absolutely pythonic to use slicing:

```
a_list = ['a','b','a','b','a']
# a_list = a_list[1:-1] # take everything but the first and last elements
a_list = a_list[:2] + a_list[-2:] # this gets you the [ 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a' ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers their question. As I read it, the list can be arbitrarily long, and OP wants to keep the first, last, and any in the middle matching their condition. In this regards, dawg's solution is better

Comment: You're correct that the wording is ambiguous. You're parsing the text OP wrote, and I'm (and dawg) are parsing the example. I think we need OP to clarify here.

Comment: Well, I’m parsing the example, too, I just thought OP meant the first few elements from the front and back of the list, and not just the very first and very last element.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a list comprehension that explicitly makes the first and last elements immune from removal, regardless of their value:

```
>>> aList = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
>>> [ letter for index, letter in enumerate(aList) if letter != 'a' or index in [0, len(x)-1] ]
['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> list_ = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
>>> [value for index, value in enumerate(list_) if index in {0, len(list_)-1} or value == 'b']
['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```

Although, the list comprehension is becoming unwieldy.  Consider writing a generator like so:

```
>>> def keep_bookends_and_bs(list_):
...     for index, value in enumerate(list_):
...         if index in {0, len(list_)-1}:
...             yield value
...         elif value == 'b':
...             yield value
...
>>> list(keep_bookends_and_bs(list_))
['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```